# Build dynamic json payload in Jmeter using Jsr223/ beanshell pre/post processer

Tags: arrays, json, object, post, jmeter

```
                    "kits": [
                            {
                            "kitHandle": "f9d162a4-3204-4e5f-841b-c45ab60abdda",
                            "locationHandle": "5e1bbca0-19c0-480a-b8ff-66e676f5f668",
                            "containerHandle": "748f217f-6e7f-4382-897b-9c5fee5a58eb",
                            "kitID": "KitID12841790",
                            "kitUsageSeq": "585",
                            "kitStatus": "QUARANTINE",
                            "shipperID": "CONT-585"
                        
                        },
                            {
                            "kitHandle": "f9d162a4-3204-4e5f-841b-c45ab60abdda",
                            "locationHandle": "5e1bbca0-19c0-480a-b8ff-66e676f5f668",
                            "containerHandle": "748f217f-6e7f-4382-897b-9c5fee5a58eb",
                            "kitID": "KitID12841790",
                            "kitUsageSeq": "585",
                            "kitStatus": "QUARANTINE",
                            "shipperID": "CONT-585"
                        
                        }
                    ],
```

so in above i need the kits block to be generated 1000 times in the request, with "kithandle" and "kitID" dynamic every time.

and below is some javascript code for generating above scenario, and i want same to be impletemented in beanshell/jsr223.

Comment: i got code in javascript

Answer (score 0):

The relevant Groovy code would be something like:

```
def kits = []

1.upto(1000, {
    def kit = [:]
    kit.put('kitHandle', 'f9d162a4-3204-4e5f-841b-c45ab60abdda')
    kit.put('locationHandle', '5e1bbca0-19c0-480a-b8ff-66e676f5f668')
    kit.put('containerHandle', '748f217f-6e7f-4382-897b-9c5fee5a58eb')
    kit.put('kitID', 'KitID12841790')
    kit.put('kitUsageSeq', '585')
    kit.put('kitStatus', 'QUARANTINE')
    kit.put('shipperID', 'CONT-585')
    kits.add(kit)
})

def payload = [kits: kits]

vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
```

the generated value can be referenced as `${payload}` where required.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter)

Comment: i got the desired payload but i need the "kitHandle' value to be dynamic for every block

Comment: "kits": [
        {
            "kitHandle": "e5e5135c-6eaa-4a9e-8300-1f5fbe5639e7",
            "locationHandle": "5e1bbca0-19c0-480a-b8ff-66e676f5f668",
            "containerHandle": "748f217f-6e7f-4382-897b-9c5fee5a58eb",
            "kitID": "KitID12841790",
            "kitUsageSeq": "585",
            "kitStatus": "QUARANTINE",
            "shipperID": "CONT-585"
        },

Comment: hi Dmitri T waiting for ur reply

Comment: @suresh, use following code: kit.put('kitHandle', UUID.randomUUID().toString())

Comment: hi @SAIR i want to remove "{" which i am getting at the starting of the array of output as below, 
{
    "kits": [
        {
            "kitHandle": "584f78c8-1ccc-4d52-941c-73e8664d7dc6",
            "locationHandle": "bb1a1f3a-3519-4e90-b30d-33fcbc9fc19f",
            "containerHandle": "754451aa-c76e-4d89-93b2-bf87b64ec65e",
            "kitID": "ccce9f10-b084-4557-8c1a-2a0cf2a433e9",
            "kitUsageSeq": "585",
            "kitStatus": "QUARANTINE",
            "shipperID": "CONT-585"
        },
     ]

Comment: hi @Dmitri T i am getting flow bracket at starting of array, i dont need it

Comment: hi while creating json builder by default { bracket is coming at starting, how tonullyfy it

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your Kithandle has resemblence as UUId, so it is Handle by using function uuid -${__UUID}

Comment: hi @pradeep ur not understanding the whole issue

Comment: Sorry to mention,..........u have mentioned-i got the desired payload but i need the "kitHandle' value to be dynamic for every block..... ,,my answer is for this question

Comment: hi @pradep i am able to genrate "kithandle" dynamic, but now the issue is payload builder, i dont want the { bracket which is being generated